# javascript sorting a json array by a given key

Tags: javascript

given

```
let jsons = [
    {
    "id": 10
    ...
  }, 
    {
    "id": 4
    ...
  }, 
    {
    "id": 1
    ...
  }, 
  ...


]
```

I want jsons to be sorted by the id e.g.

```
let jsons = [
    {
      "id": 1
      ...
    }, 
    {
      "id": 2
      ...
    }, 
    {
      "id": 3
      ...
    }, 
    ...
]
```

This is what I have done to do this (but its extremely inefficient)

```
let jsons = [
    {
    "id": 10
    
  }, 
    {
    "id": 4
    
  }, 
    {
    "id": 1
    
  }, 
  
]

let new_list = []
length = jsons.length
for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  let index = 0
  let cur_lowest = 50000 // not sure how to get an infinite upper_bound
  for(let j = 0; j < jsons.length; j++) {
    if(jsons[j].id <= cur_lowest) {
        cur_lowest = jsons[j].id
      index = j
    }
  }
  new_list.push(jsons[index])
  jsons.splice(index, 1)
}
console.log(new_list);
```

So this works I did it here https://jsfiddle.net/xceybhLg/5/

But is there a simpler way? Preferably with like the sorted function I think it can attach on keys but reading the documentation I don't really understand it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why cant you use a simple sort function that accepts a list and the key against which the sort action is to be performed.

```js
let jsons = [
  { "id": 10 },
  { "id": 4 },
  { "id": 1 },
];
function sortList(list, key) {
  return list.sort((a, b) => a[key] - b[key]);
}
const new_list = sortList(jsons, 'id');
console.log(new_list);
```

Comment: Just be careful, this only works on numeric properties

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted! Is there a way to make this in descending order as well (e.g. 10, 4, 1)?

Comment: list.sort((a, b) => b[key] - a[key]);